# How to free up facet_grid() width in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, facet-grid

My question is probably simple, but I couldn't find the solution. So any help would be very much appreciated. What I want to do is free up the width of the grids in facet_grid. I know that "free_x" should work, but it doesn't. facet_wrap() neither do the job.

The code is:

```
set.seed(1233)
means <- c(rep(20, 20), rep(60, 60), rep(120, 120))
sds <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 60), rep(4, 120))
values <- rnorm(length(means), mean = means, sd = sds)
stage <- sample(c(rep("a", 20), rep("b", 60), rep("c", 120)))
df <- data.frame(cbind(values, stage))
rm(values)


graph_builder <- function(data_set, y_axis_parameter, category, attribute_name) {
  graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x=seq(length({{y_axis_parameter}})),
                                y={{y_axis_parameter}}, colour= {{category}})) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(cols= vars({{category}})) +
    ylab(paste0(attribute_name, " Measured Values")) +
    xlab("Data Points") +
    labs(title = paste0(attribute_name)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ 
    theme(legend.position = "none") 
  
  graph
}


graph_builder(df, values, stage, "Test")
```

The issue is that if my stage categories are in order, such as 1-20: 'a,' 20-80: 'b,' and 80-200: 'c,' then the grids are shown respectively. However, I want each grid to start displaying data points from 1 to the length() of the number of data points for each category. It seems that facet_grid works based on the index, and I don't want that. Adding `'scales='free_x', space='free_x'` in facet grid isn't my solution. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
graph_builder <- function(data_set, y_axis_parameter, category, attribute_name) {
  data_set <- data_set |>
    mutate(x = row_number(), .by = {{ category }})
  
  graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(
    x = x,
    y = {{ y_axis_parameter }}, colour = {{ category }},
    group = 1
  )) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(cols = vars({{ category }}), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
    ylab(paste0(attribute_name, " Measured Values")) +
    xlab("Data Points") +
    labs(title = paste0(attribute_name)) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none")

  graph
}


graph_builder(df, values, stage, "Test")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is exactly what I am looking for. For learning purposes, I have a follow-up question. It seems that we end up with an inconsistent number of breaks in the grids for each category, and it looks kind of weird in my graph. I tried "scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 9)" to get consistent or a better way of breaks, but interestingly, it creates a different number of breaks for each category, and I was wondering why?

Comment: Yup. `n.breaks` serves as a "An integer guiding the number of major breaks. The algorithm may choose a slightly different number to ensure nice break labels." If you want more fine control about the breaks then have a look at `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` which allows to set the scale individually per panel.

Comment: Also, I realized that in this way of visualizing data, the more data there is in one category, the more dominant that part becomes in the visualization, which makes perfect sense. But what if I want an equal width of grids in the graph? Can I manipulate the size of the grids?

Comment: Sure. If you want an equal width drop `space="free_x"`. And for more control have a look at `ggh4x::facet_manual` which allows to set the width of each panel manually.